# Extra solution folder getting created in multi-project templates

Tags: vsix, project-template

I have created a multi Project template and published it in VS via VSIX. My problem is when I create a new project via the template an extra solution folder is getting created which contains all the projects and solution file is getting created one level up the hierarchy.

Actual result: -> SoltnName folder

```
                       --> SoltnName Folder

                             ------>Project1Folder

                             ------>Project2Folder

                       --> Solutn File
```

Expected Result: -> SoltnName folder

```
                                 ---->Project1Folder

                                 ---->Project2Folder

                                 ----> Solutn File
```

I tried by setting property CreateNewFolder to False in solution level template file & it's not working. I checked other posts as well and didn't find any good workaround on this. Is there any way I can handle the situation?

Comment: You need to maintain the same structure in your project template zip file. Have you checked it?

Comment: Yes, I am maintaining the same structure. I read some posts & I found it's default behavior when we create a new project with solution using MultiProject template. Is any any way I can override the default behavior?